# online resources for database design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have worked with Databases before; however never designed a Database. For this project I have an opportunity to design a database. I am looking for an online resource(s) that are introductory level. Something that help me decide how to decide on all the tables that I'll need and how to establish relationships among them.

Thank You

Comment: Should be in community wiki, I believe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read a book about DB fundamentals first. There are plenty of DB fundamental information online. Just google it, and you will find plenty. This one is a good introductory primer - http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx - just move on from there. There are way too many books to list here... You would also look at text books from college courses...